# Какртинка шера не отображается на стене в вк на мобильных? Метод vk.share

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, sharing

Для шеринга в вк использую ссылку https://vk.com/share.php?
туда в качестве гет-параметров передаю картинку, заголовок, описание, урл

В мета тегах есть тег twitter:image
вместо него вставляю ссылку на иллюстрацию.
из документации вк

*Иллюстрация. Если на публикуемой странице есть теги og:image, twitter:image, image, то адрес изображения для иллюстрации будет взят из указанного первым*

Раньше прекрасно работало как на мобильных, так и на десктопе. Но теперь почему-то если шерить с chrome android например (там m.vk/share?php), то картинка не отображается. Она есть в превью, но после публикации ее не оказывается на стене. С десктопа все отлично

Answer (score 0):

Мобильный share сейчас в целом не умеет в картинки, хоть и показывает их в превью.

Comment: А где про это написано в доке? Вообще нет никакой инфы....

Comment: Вдруг неожиданно перестало работать